# I have a problem with double quote in vs code

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

When I press Double Quote like this "". The Cursor is going to the end automatically, this is natural. I want to take the cursor inside of the double-quote automatically when pressing double quote. Another thing I need to press two times is to appear double quote. How to fix this in vs code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This happens to me as well but could not find related keyword shortcut to disable or change it

Answer (score 2):

In VS Code, go to File > Preferences > Settings  (or Ctrl+,). When the Settings page opens you should already be in the Search box (if not, click inside the Search box). Type "quotes" (without the quotes) inside the Search box.

Check each entry in the resulting list of settings. You may have to experiment to find which setting needs to be changed.

In particular, look at

```
Editor: Auto Closing Quotes
Controls whether the editor should automatically close quotes after the user adds an opening quote.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please first go to `Keyboard Shortcuts` then double click one of random keybinding and press `"`, it will display an informative text like `1 similar keybindings found` click this to find related operation. You can delete or change that to prevent vscode jumping the end of the page or the last active tab when pressing `"`